# How do I send meeting updates in Outlook to new attendees only?

Tags: updates, meetings

Up until recently, I was able to add meeting attendees and send the updated meeting invite to the new attendees only.  Now I can't.  When I add a new attendee and send the update, I don't get the pop-up box which allows me to choose "send meeting update to new attendees only".  Please can users tell me if I need to change a setting somewhere?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I find that if the invitees don't respond to the initial invite, they will still get the updates until they either accept or decline.  It's what seems to be happening on my end.  My fix to anyone that reaches out is to either accept or decline to stop it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

- Double-click to open the meeting, then use the To line or the Scheduling Assistant to add one or more people to the meeting.
- Click Send and then select one of the following: Send updates only to added or deleted attendees. Send updates to all attendees.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/calendaring/send-updates-prompt-not-displayed

That option do not exist anymore.
Its now processed automaticly from the server side.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! While this link may answer the question it is better to quote the important parts and include the linked site as reference only as the linked content might change, rendering your answer useless.

Answer (score 0):

From the MS website "These options were removed from Outlook clients, and the code logic was moved to the server. Now, if an update to the attendee list is the only change that's made to an existing meeting, the server automatically sends a meeting update notification to only the added or deleted attendees."

However, this is not really the case. For instance, today I added someone to a meeting (that I was working via separate emails to potentially reschedule) when I added the new person I immediately received a response from someone else saying that it was still showing the original date - they never should have received a notification. This is a frustrating change.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/calendaring/send-updates-prompt-not-displayed
This page like others mentioned states that the option has been removed from the client, this is not the correct/complete answer though.
"These options were removed from Outlook clients, and the code logic was moved to the server. Now, if an update to the attendee list is the only change that's made to an existing meeting, the server automatically sends a meeting update notification to only the added or deleted attendees."

HOWEVER, the following states:
"This change affects only clients that run Outlook for Windows that has the new calendar sharing improvements enabled. **The notifications will continue to be displayed in Outlook for Windows** when you edit meetings in **your own calendar** or if the calendar sharing improvements are disabled."

Meaning this function should still work even if you have the option enabled. The server side logic should only apply to shared calendars, not your own.

Sadly I am experiencing the same issue as the poster. The pop-up asking to send updates shows itself inconsistently. Testing in exactly the same scenario's sometimes does and sometimes doesn't show the pop-up.
I'd like to get some more clarity on why this happens and how to fix it.